# What does has_one exactly do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

On which level does Rails' `has_one` operates?

Example:

```
class User 
  has_one :comment
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I open two tabs in browser with form to create a comment (`user_id` is taken from `current_user.id`), input data, click save in each tab.

Now I have two valid comments with same `user_id`.

I am sure that adding `uniqueness: true` to user presence validation in Comment model will do the job of preventing saving multiple comments with same `user_id`:

```
validates :user,
  presence: true,
  uniqueness: true
```

But what is `has_one` responsible for then?

Comment: Now, if you do `user.comment` you'll get one comment back, not two. That's what it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exactly? This:

```
  # File activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb, line 1405
  def has_one(name, scope = nil, options = {})
    reflection = Builder::HasOne.build(self, name, scope, options)
    Reflection.add_reflection self, name, reflection
  end
```

Sources:

https://github.com/rails/docrails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L1405

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: have a +1 for "exactly this". One should be careful with wording of their questions :)

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that `uniqueness: true` will not be enforced at the db level, so that it is susceptible to "race conditions".

Comment: I don't find this answer helpful. The OP clearly wants to know what the intendet use for `has_one` is, not how it is implemented. The implementation is not readable for people not having a good understanding of the RoR framework, either.

Comment: @SvenKoschnicke I disagree that it is unhelpful. It was made half in jest, but the other half is dead serious. This is how one gets better at Rails (and asking more specific questions). All of the best Rails developers I know dive right into the Rails code when a question like this comes up. I have provided an entry point for such research as well as additional information on uniqueness validations.

Comment: @BradWerth: Then a link to the documentation of `has_one` would have been better. I agree with you that reading the source is a very good way to learn things, but the question suggests very little familiarity with the framework, and in this case I think a better entry point would be the documentation.

Comment: @SvenKoschnicke point well taken, additional documentation link added.

Comment: good one, I wouldn't resist as well ;) +1 and most likely a checkmark

Answer (score 5):

`has_one` allows you to query for the first comment associated with the user using `user.comment`, which will evaluate SQL similar to `select * from comments where comments.user_id == USER_ID limit 1`. In this case, you may be looking for `has_many`, which returns multiple comments.

It does not enforce that there exists exactly one comment per user, however. If you really do want only one comment per user, you should set up the user_id as a unique column on comments, enforced on the database level (which `uniqueness: true` does not do).